# Filter data using histogram in C

Tags: c, arduino, range, sensors

I have 25 values from a sensor between 0 and 40.

Most values will be around the true real value but some can be far away.

How can I get a reliable measure based on the values?

Mean will not work as lower or higher values will blow up the average.

Lets suppose we have these values:

```
10, 13, 22, 21, 19, 18, 20, 21, 22, 21, 19, 30, 30, 21, 20, 21, 22, 19, 18, 20, 22, 21, 10, 18, 19
```

I think best approach will be using histogram. Defining manual ranges will fail as we can reject some good values next to range bounds.
Automatic ranges calculated from the incoming data wont work because they can overlap each other.

I am coding over Arduino so memory allocation will not be the best idea.

Comment: You picked some questionable tags for this.  I realize you want to code it in C but the question doesn't otherwise have anything to do with C.  I would almost suggest [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) for this as it seems more statistical than anything.

Comment: Didnt know it exists, will try there. However I am working with Arduino so most 'C like' solutions will fit me or can be adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter I have ended used is a multiple mean.
I process the mean of all values, then discard those values over a threshold from the first mean and then I compute the mean of the left values.

Comment: Maybe You could share some code? This would help people lime me to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be a moving average will be a nice choice, define the length say `d` then at any instant your filtered value will be the average of the previous `d` sensor values.

If you really concern about deleting some `strange` values, you may set a `threshold` in addition to your moving average, but i don't recommend it, i guess you have to observe the real pattern your sensor is following.

P.S: My answer could be opinion-based, but this is the way i deal with sensors [in my work] and this is working perfectly for the company up to now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calculating the [Trimmed Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) of these values could help you, or just
the median.

[How to calculate the truncated or trimmed mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/how-to-calculate-the-truncated-or-trimmed-mean)

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually after an average, this won't work for you, but this method requires no extra memory to manage a buffer of samples:

```
void loop() {
  static float mean = analogRead(A0);
  int newInput = analogRead(A0);
  mean = (mean * 0.95) + (newInput * 0.05);
  Serial.println(mean);
}
```

You can adjust the constants (0.95 and 0.05) to whatever you like, as long as they add up to 1. The smaller the multiplier of `mean`, the faster `mean` will track new values.

If you don't like the overhead of floating point math, the same idea works quite well in fixed point.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This will work in real-time. Nice for other approaches.